# How do I make an ActionEvent and a KeyEvent fire the same action?

Tags: java, event-handling, applet, keyevent

I'm writing an applet and want to figure out how to make a button and a key event cover the same bit of code.  For this question, I'll call this button `fireButton`.  The code for the action event would of course look like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (e.getSource() == fireButton) {
      //all the code that pressing button executes
   }  
}
```

Now, I want pressing the 'enter' key to perform the same code that the action event handles, but I do not want to rewrite all the code again in a `keyPressed` method.

To be specific, I'm writing a battleship program, and the 'Fire' button takes input from two textFields, handles exceptions, and passes the input as parameters to a method that fires at a particular square in the grid.  Ideally, pressing the enter key would function the same way as if I had pressed the fire button.  Is there a way to make a certain method call an `actionPerformed` method?  If not, what would be an elegant solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an Action
2. Add the Action to the JButton
3. Use Key Bindings to bind the Enter key to the Action

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. How to Use Actions
2. How to Use Key Bindings

If you are just talking about invoking the "Fire" button with the enter key then check out [Enter Key and Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for a couple of approaches.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put all the code in a separate method that receives all the relevant data from the event (if any) as parameters:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == fireButton) {
        Object relevantData0 = new Object(); // e.getSomething();
        Object relevantData1 = new Object(); // e.getSomethingElse();
        handleFireAction(relevantData1, relevantData2);
    }
}  

public void actionPerformed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == fireButton) {
        Object relevantData0 = new Object(); // e.getSomething();
        Object relevantData1 = new Object(); // e.getSomethingElse();
        handleFireAction(relevantData1, relevantData2);
    }
}  

private void handleFireAction(Object relevantData0, Object relevantData1) { // Object relevantDat2, and so on
    //all the code that pressing button executes
}
```

If you don't need any data from the event its even easier ;)
This way you just write your code once for both events. It's a general OO aproach.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) I would recommend you have a controller class which handles these sorts of requests. Then all you have to do is delegate to the controller in each event handler.

Like so:

```
public class BattleShipController {

   public void handleFireAction() {
   // ...
   }
}

//-- in your UI class(es)
private BattleShipController _controller = new BattleShipController();

//-- in event calls:
_controller.handleFireAction();
```

If you post relevant code I can make further suggestions.